# My windows FTP server unable to access remotely on some networks

Tags: vb6, ftp

I have setup a windows 2003 ftp server and using chilkat to connect to this ftp inside my customized application. My application is developed in VB6 with ftp support of chilkat. The application works on different places of the city and connects to my ftp. **Unable to access ftp and transfer files using the customised application, from some networks like idea netsetter / bsnl**. It works perfect on other networks.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sam

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to be a firewall issue at the client end.  FTP is often blocked by firewalls.

Just as well, FTP has its problems making it a less than ideal alternative.  There are better options such as SFTP or FTPS but support for those is limited in Windows and you'll have to buy both server and client pieces to use one of them.

Fewer firewalls block HTTP and HTTPS though some are finicky enough to block traffic that doesn't look like Web browsing.  Stiil, your odds of success go up substantially.

An obvious choice might be to use WebDAV.  IIS supports WebDAV and it is pretty easy to write simple WebDAV client logic in VB6 based on one of the many HTTP components available.  I'd probably use XmlHttpRequest or WinHttpRequest for that.  A search ought to turn up several VB6 classes written to wrap one of them to support WebDAV client operations.  You can also buy WebDAV client libraries.

Stick to using HTTPS (which means you need a server cetificate for IIS) and you won't have passwords going over the network in the clear.  Even if you use HTTP you'll be no worse off than using FTP, plus it'll work through the vast majority of firewalls except those that specifically block non-browsing HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a firewall configuration on the Client or Server.  You're not going to be able to do much about the client, but for the server it may depend on whether your doing Active or Passive FTP connections.

If you are doing Active connections, make sure ports 20 and 21 are open.

If you're doing Passive connections, you may want to check out this article about configuring the PassivePortRange in Server 2003 FTP- http://support.microsoft.com/?id=555022.